# OpenSeadragon missing prop in types definition

Tags: reactjs, typescript, openseadragon

I have an application written in React Typescript and use OpenSeadragon (https://openseadragon.github.io/) to display images. To get type definitions for OpenSeadragon I use @types/openseadragon: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/openseadragon

I want to use the toolbar prop coming from OpenSeadragon (https://openseadragon.github.io/examples/ui-toolbar/), however, this prop is missing in the types definition. So, when I try to use the prop in the code as so:

```
OpenSeadragon({
                id: 'openseadragon-container',
                toolbar: 'toolbarDiv',
            });
```

I get the following error:

> (property) toolbar: string Argument of type '{ id: string; toolbar:
> string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Options'.   Object
> literal may only specify known properties, and 'toolbar' does not
> exist in type 'Options'.

I am wondering if there are any way to overcome this and how I can be able to use the toolbar prop ? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this would be to create an `interface` of the `Options` type and include the `toolbar` in there. So you would extend the existing `Options` type and include all the parameters you need.

```js
interface OptionsWithToolbar extends OpenSeadragon.Options {
  toolbar: string;
}

OpenSeadragon({
  id: "openseadragon-container",
  toolbar: "toolbarDiv"
} as OptionsWithToolbar);
```